# How to parse a dataframe with dictionary rows in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataset that returns multiple rows in a single column like this one:

```
{'billingaddresscountry':'Brasil','ip':'187.78.30.72','billingcpf':'001.022.614-61','billingphoneddi':'55','billingphoneddd':'81','billingphonenumber':'8815-2111','date':'2012-07-10T01:05:59.6177731-03:00'}
```

AND like this

```
{'billingcpf':'324.625.318-43','billingphoneddi':'55','billingphoneddd':'11','billingphonenumber':'989523447','billingaddresscountry':'Brasil','paymentaddresscountry':'Brasil'}
```

EDIT:
I have thousands of rows in my dataset that look similar to this. They all have different number of keys in the dictionary. How can I put it inside a dataframe with column names as the keys and rows as values.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Double double quotation marks `""` are illegal in Python. Please fix your code.

Comment: Do you mean that the dataset will return multiple dictionaries (one for each row)? Or a single dictionary with many entries in it? From your question its not very clear to me.

Comment: I have many rows with a dictionary inside of them. Similar to those in the examples. I want to get these and put them inside a single dataframe with null values when a key is not matched in a string.

Comment: @DYZ double quotation marks are fine in Python, not sure where you got that. Single are preferred in some situations, but you won't even get PEP8 warnings.

Comment: @grismar The OP used double double quotation marks (they fixed it now).

Comment: Ah, "double double" - I assume OP got the content from a string also surrounded by double quotation marks, because double double quotation marks are supported in Python as a way to escape double quotation marks in a string expressed in double quotation marks. But you're right that the original post was wrong, as it lacked the outer marks - not for lack of support in Python though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing this very straightforward solution?

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'billingaddresscountry': 'Brasil', 'ip': '187.78.30.72', 'billingcpf': '001.022.614-61', 'billingphoneddi': '55',
     'billingphoneddd': '81', 'billingphonenumber': '8815-2111', 'date': '2012-07-10T01:05:59.6177731-03:00'},
    {'billingcpf': '324.625.318-43', 'billingphoneddi': '55', 'billingphoneddd': '11',
     'billingphonenumber': '989523447', 'billingaddresscountry': 'Brasil', 'paymentaddresscountry': 'Brasil'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

To give you a better sense of the result:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
    # different order
    {'b': 4, 'a': 5, 'c': 6},
    # missing values
    {'b': 7, 'c': 8},
    # new columns introduced later
    {'a': 9, 'd': 10},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
     a    b    c     d
0  1.0  2.0  3.0   NaN
1  5.0  4.0  6.0   NaN
2  NaN  7.0  8.0   NaN
3  9.0  NaN  NaN  10.0
```

You indicated you don't want to add all the lines at once, due to volume:

```
df = df.append([{'a': 11, 'e': 12}])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
      a    b    c     d     e
0   1.0  2.0  3.0   NaN   NaN
1   5.0  4.0  6.0   NaN   NaN
2   NaN  7.0  8.0   NaN   NaN
3   9.0  NaN  NaN  10.0   NaN
0  11.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  12.0
```

Comment: ok,I see it working for those two lines, ButI have 500k+ rows like those you worked. So I would have to copy and paste them all, it wouldn't be pretty. But I'll keep it in mind! Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to 'copy and paste', you just read them in into a list - you *would be* right however that you'd need to keep them all in memory. If that's your problem, or you have further issues, you should include that in the question - I merely answered the question you posed.

Comment: hm... cool, didn't think of that. I'm new to python and programming, didn't know I could do that easily

Comment: No problem - StackOverflow is here to solve exactly that problem. However, you should always try to provide all the information that fully describes your problem, to get the most useful answers (and help others with the same question). Not everyone is willing to go in and keep adding to answers for more detail.